# jQuery click doesn't apply the second time

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. I tried to find solution but no results. The problem: the first time, it correctly changes the language, but just once. What can I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"><h2>Dropdowns</h2>
    <div class="dropdown font-weight-bold">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"  data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="selected">FR</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item language" href="#">It</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item language" href="#">De</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item language" href="#">Fr</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item language" href="#">En</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".language").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var currentlanguage = $(this).text();
        console.log(currentlanguage);
        $("#selected").replaceWith(currentlanguage);
    });
});
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("#selected").html(currentlanguage);` or `$("#selected").text(currentlanguage);` instead of `$("#selected").replaceWith(currentlanguage);`

Your code is replacing the `("#selected")` span with the text. So `#selected` span doesn't exist the next time you change the language.

So you just need to change the HTML of that span. Not the span itself.

Comment: Or use `text()` since there is no html involved

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your comment. I have updated answer to incorporate your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call. Hence `#selected` div isn't present when you click second time.

Try `.text()` instead, since there is no html tags involved

```
$("#selected").text(currentlanguage);
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c6st5o6u/)